# can not run node with sublime text 2 in windows

Tags: node.js, sublimetext2

It shows that

Node binary could not be found in PATH

Consider using the node_command setting for the Node plugin

why it can not find my environment variables, [which is in the PATH(in the third and fourth line from the bottom)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3qz9.jpg)

and here is my settings

```
{ 
    // save before running commands  
  "save_first": true,  
  // if present, use this command instead of plain "node"  
  // e.g. "/usr/bin/node" or "C:\bin\node.exe"  
  // e.g. "/usr/bin/node" or "C:\bin\node.exe"  
  "node_command": "C:\\Program Files\nodejs\node",   
  // Same for NPM command  
  "npm_command": "C:\\Program Files\nodejs\npm",   
  // as 'NODE_PATH' environment variable for node runtime  
  //"node_path": false,  

  "expert_mode": false,  

  "ouput_to_new_tab": false  
}
```

here is my build

```
  "cmd": ["node", "$file"],
  "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.js",
  "shell":true,
  "encoding": "cp936",
  "windows":
    {
        "cmd": ["taskkill","/F", "/IM", "node.exe","&","node", "$file"]  
    },
  "linux":
    {
        "cmd": ["killall node; node", "$file"]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your paths like so:

```
"node_command": "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node",   
"npm_command": "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\npm",
```

Note the double backslashes `\\` as directory deliminators. When you start the path with a double backslash after `C:`, Sublime expects *all* deliminators to be double backslashes. Alternatively, you could make them all single forward slashes:

```
"node_command": "C:/Program Files/nodejs/node",   
"npm_command": "C:/Program Files/nodejs/npm",
```

As far as your `PATH` is concerned, you should remove the trailing `\` from `C:\Program Files\nodejs\`. This is probably what's causing Sublime to not check that directory.